# android universal image loader for two listview in viewpager

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-viewpager, universal-image-loader

I am using `universalImageLoader` in my android program.

### My situation:

- 1 viewpager(2 pages)
- one listview on first page,  one gridview on second page.
- the listview shows images downloading from internet(lazy load),
- the gridview shows images that are on SD card.

Both use `universalImageLoader` to load image.

## my problem:

First, turn to page 1 of the viewpager, when the network speed is very slow, all the thread in `universalImageLoader` pool is downloading images of the listview, at this time , turn to page 2 of the viewpager, the gridview is empty, 'cause all the thread is downloading image, we have to wait until all the image finished downloading, and then we can see the images in gridview appeared(the images in gridview should've been shown quickly with no lag, for they are on SD card).

I want to clear the downloading thread pool of `UniversalImageLoader` and add new local image request when user turn to page2 so that the images on SD card can be shown quickly, but I didn't find a way to do this. there's no `clearRequest()` method for `UniversalImageLoader`

Any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Manually add ImageView items to the gridview in code. That should work in displaying the grid with all the images already loaded

Comment: @Pierre that will have the risk of OutOfMemoryError, for UniversalImageLoader manages the downloading image and you manage the local image yourself, both will think the memory is enough but all the images add up may exceed memory limit. also, I want to figure out a way to let UniversalImageLoader to handle all the image

Comment: Maybe try to resize your images, create thumbnails of all the images which is smaller and will automatically load way faster. And then onclick load the original image. Maybe something in that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `ImageLoader.stop()` when user turn to page2. It clears thread pool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  By the way, setting .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO) can achieve a pleasing result too.